# Proper way of calling AddRef() inside QueryInterface() implementation

Tags: c++, windows, com

I found some implementation pattern of `QueryInterface()` along these lines:

> ```
> // Inside some COM object implementation ...
>
> virtual HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
> {
>     *ppv = /* Find interface ... */
>     if (*ppv == nullptr)
>         return E_NOINTERFACE;
>
>     static_cast<IUnknown *>(*ppv)->AddRef();  // ###         
>     return S_OK;
> }
> ```

The line of interest is the one marked with the `// ###` comment.

Is calling `AddRef()` on the `IUnknown` `static_cast`-pointer really necessary? Or is it just useless boilerplate code?
In other words, would a simple `AddRef()` call (i.e. `this->AddRef()`) be just fine? If not, why?

Comment: If interface->AddRef maps to this->AddRef then I suppose you could just use `this`, but is that always the case?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Let's assume that the above code is part of some COM object implementation like `class CSomeComponent : public IInterface1, public IInterface2 { ... };`. What would be wrong with a simple `AddRef();` call, instead of `static_cast<IUnknown*>(*ppv)->AddRef();` call?

Comment: BTW: In [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879357.aspx) - following the aforementioned AddRef calling pattern - it reads that _"[...] AddRef is called through the resulting interface pointer again to support some rare but permissible class composition scenarios"_. I wonder what these scenarios are and what are the technical reasons for that AddRef() "call-style"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you normally have only *one* AddRef() implementation so it doesn't matter how you call it.   Note how the way the code uses `ppv` was the possible inspiration, it is typeless (void**) so a cast is needed.  Maybe a tear-off would make you do this differently.

Answer (score 2):

The main reasons are tear-off interface pointers (e.g. for rarely used interfaces) and aggregable objects (the COM equivalent of mixins, more or less).

In these cases (a tear-off, or an aggregator when asked for an aggregated IID), the `ppv` is not an interface pointer to the same ref-counted C++ object.  As such, that code is necessary if you want to support these cases just as well.

By calling `this->AddRef`, perhaps you earn a bit of simplicity or type safety, but at the cost of not supporting interfaces not explicitly implemented by the same C++ object.

---

P.S.: Contrary to what most books and documentation say, in my opinion:

1. Aggregation is more similar to using mixins than it is to inheritance or composition;
2. Aggregation is actually a special case of (cached) tear-off interface pointers as opposed to a special case of composition.

Here's my line of thought:

1. When you inherit, you usually have the chance to override (virtual) methods, which is not the case with aggregation due to direct method calls; when you use composition, you may have to wrap inbound objects as to not let the inner object leak its identity to a given object (e.g. the inner object might pass itself to some method of the inbound object), whereas aggregation also means sharing identity by having two sets of `IUnknown`'s methods on aggregable objects, thus not having this particular problem at all;
2. A tear-off has its own lifetime, whereas an aggregable object shares its lifetime with the outer object.  Otherwise, either may be created only when needed, although aggregators usually create aggregable objects as soon as they themselves are created.

Answer (score 0):

The interface returned need not be a base class of the class implementing `QueryInterface`.

Comment: I don't get it... Could you please elaborate? Thanks. Why would a simple `AddRef()` call be wrong?